# Stochastic Processes

Tags: self-study, correlation, stochastic-processes

I have a couple questions about stochastic processes. My professor didn't really give in depth explanations and non of his lecture slides do much explaining either.

Say S(x) is a stochastic variable whose properties depend on a 2-dimensional stochastic field. I know that this this is second order stationary if the mean stays constant over time and the variance does not depend on time (though may depend on lag). I understand that isotropy is the lack of a preferred direction over time, but what is the mathematical statement of the isotropic conditions?

The other question I have is given two processes:

$x_t = .1*x_{t-1} + \epsilon$ where epsilon is white noise ($\epsilon \sim N(0,1^2)$ and

$y_t = x_t^2$

What is the correlation between the two? I get that correlation is $E[(y_t - E[y_t] \cdot (x_t - E[x_t])]$, but every time I try to solve it I end up with 0 which doesn't make sense.

Comment: I understand both of these questions now. Not deleting since Aksakal helped me understand the second part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think of this: no matter what is $x_{t-1}$, $x_t$ will tend to be smaller in absolute value. So regardless of $x_0$, expectation of $x_t$ must be collapsing to 0.

Correlation of $x$ and $y$ is proportional to $E[xy]-E[x]E[y]=E[xy]=E[x^3]$. You know that $E[x\varepsilon]=0$, so $E[x^3]$ must be the skewness of the normal distribution.

Comment: Yeah, I knew $E(x_t)$ was tending to 0, assuming there were enough observations. And since the skewness of the normal distribution is 0, the correlation is 0? edit: Ah. This makes sense, sorry I was thinking about a linear pattern, not an AR(1) pattern. I get that correlation is 0 now. Thanks!